# TF2 Scripting: Action Slot

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'm trying to make a script that spams the snow-flake noise maker but couldn't get it to work nor any I found on google. I tried figuring out what was wrong and it seems that "use_action_slot_item" is no longer a recognized command?

I typed use_action_slot_item right into the console and it says "command not found". Did valve update this or something? Here's a screenie if you want to check it: http://snag.gy/p7GQ0.jpg

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `+use_action_slot_item` instead — with the `+`.

Comment: Thanks! I really wish there was some official documentation on this stuff.